# Client Side Javascript Button Not Working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, client, client-side

I am trying to calculate a the proper divisors of a function when the user inputs a value and hits calculate. I am able to get the result to display on the HTML side, however the function will not calucate the proper divisors and instead takes the value of "sum" only. What am I doing wrong?

```js
function sumOfProperDivisors() {
  return sum;
}

var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
var sum = 0;

{
  for (i = 1; i <= input; i++)
    if (input % i == 0)
      sum = sum + i;
}

function display() {

  document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = "<b> Sum = " + sumOfProperDivisors();

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Sum of Prop. Div.</title>
  <h2> Sum of Proper Divisors </h2>
</head>

<body style="background-color:teal;">

  <p> Enter a Positive Integer (N): </p>
  <input type="number" id="input">

  <p><button onclick="display()">Calculate the Sum of Divisors</button></p>

  <div></div>

  <script src="sumOfPDivs.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: move the calculation code into sumOfProperDivisors() method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `sumOfProperDivisors()` should be something like this:

```
    function sumOfProperDivisors(){
     var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
     var sum = 0;
     {
        for (i=1; i<=input; i++)
        if (input%i==0)
        sum = sum + i;
        return sum; 
    }
```

As your algoritm of caluculating sum is outside function, it's not working at all.

Answer (score 2):

Move your calcultaion logic inside `sumOfProperDivisors()` function like below:-

```js
function sumOfProperDivisors() {
  var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var sum = 0;
  for (i=1; i<=input; i++){
    if (input%i==0){
      sum = sum + i;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}

function display(){
  document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = "<b> Sum = " + sumOfProperDivisors();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Sum of Prop. Div.</title>
<h2> Sum of Proper Divisors </h2>
</head>
<body style="background-color:teal;">

<p> Enter a Positive Integer (N): </p>
<input type="number" id="input">

<p><button onclick="display()">Calculate the Sum of Divisors</button></p>

<div></div>

<script src="sumOfPDivs.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

***Note:-*** since logic is outside of the function so actually it's not working at-all

Answer (score 1):

When your page will be loaded, your text box will have no value, and sum will be calculated at the time of page loading, because code to calculate sum is outside any function, So it is better to put the code in function sumOfProperDivisors, so that it takes value from text box on every click and then calculate sum.